# UIImagePicker controller how to display some images of photo album on the storyboard and allow user to expand to chose from other images?

Tags: swift

I am able to load images manually with a button using UIIMagePicker Controller. 
   I have seen a lot of apps which display some of your images like 3-4 of them, then there is a little arrow over that image set where you can expand and you can see your entire photo album and you can choose which photo you want to load.
   I want to know , do I have to implement that from scratch or there is a ready made version available in swift?

Comment: Can you please specify what apps do what you want or post a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For selecting photos **UIImagePickerController** is the easiest way to make selections that Apple gives us.  This supports picking images by navigating by albums or your entire camera-roll.

Unfortunately **UIImagePickerController** is also completely uncustomizable.  So if you want make something that deviates from the standard selection/look/usage of **UIImagePickerController** at all you have to recreate it yourself by getting asset references from the [ALAssetLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/index.html) and putting them into a **UICollectionView** yourself.

There are some github projects that have done this, although there aren't  any well developed Swift ones yet, a few Objective-C ones do exist, which will still work in a Swift project anyways by simple importing it your projects bridging-header file.

**[UzysAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/uzysjung/UzysAssetsPickerController)**

[WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/wessmith/WSAssetPickerController)

[ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController)

[Here](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/79defb828be0b26ff549e5cdae4d23e145e407ce/AppMessage/AppMessage/Controlers/ChatViewController.swift) is an example of a project using **UzysAssetPickerController** from swift.

[Using UzysAssetPickerController with Swift](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/79defb828be0b26ff549e5cdae4d23e145e407ce/AppMessage/AppMessage/Controlers/ChatViewController.swift)

If what you are actually trying to do is a single line list of images, like in iMessage, or a combination of these two selection methods check out **[ImagePickerSheetController](https://github.com/larcus94/ImagePickerSheetController)**, which is written in Swift.